# Which country has the most snow days in Europe?

Tags: cold-weather, snow, snowboarding

For snowboarding reasons I need to know which country has the most "snow days" (is it even called like that?). I don't mean the highest snow height or something. Just the time when it's white outside. :) A snow-fall analogy to the "[sunshine hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_duration)".

I guess it's a battle between Scandinavian countries, Austria and Switzerland, isn't it?

Comment: It certainly isn't England!

Comment: @Aravona That wouldn't be fair... Your state can't be superior in every way :P

Comment: What are you planning to do? Off-piste tours and maybe even alpine tours?

Comment: @Wills We just considered to move to a country for a couple of months (half of a year or so?) and we want to "hike'n'board" :).

Comment: Likely norway, Sweeden or Finland I'd imagine. Especially in the Arctic circle!

Comment: What do you mean with "when it's white outside"? There're regions where it's withe outside all the year. And on glaciers you can go snowboarding all the year. So moving to the Alps (Italy, Germany, France, Switzerland, Austria) in winter, you'll have the best conditions I think.

Comment: I mean snowing... Take "sunshine hours" as an analogy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_duration

Comment: you should probably care more about whether it has mountains or not.

Comment: Why do you want it to be snowing? Isn't it better if there is a ton of snow already, and the sun is shinning?

Comment: Do you mean it is snowing or snow on the ground? Either way i think its probably Scandinavia. For the later glaciers have snow all year

Comment: @nivag Basically "snow on the ground" but I guess that this isn't really measurable. That's why I would go with the snowing days :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scandinavia is a good option, the more north you go the better. For me the nature there is more remote, more 'raw' compared to the Alps. So I would think it's comparable with Canada (although I've never been to those regions).

If you can choose when to go, why not go during winter time. You can add late autumn and early spring too. In this timespan you could have a great time in the Alps. Either Austria or going 'deeper' that means moving more into the Western Alps. In Switzerland, France and Italy you can find the high mountains of Europe where you can hike a lot. During winter you can do really a lot of snowboarding. You find a lot of prepared tracks too. You need to know that the Alps are touristic developed pretty much that means you find a lot to do and especially lot of easy accessible activities to do.

I wouldn't choose just by the days with snow. There is more than that. Think of culture, cities you wanna visit or in general what you are planning to see besides mountains (although I understand your point of view -_-)

Here are some examples where to go if you are searching snow:
http://www.geo.de/GEO/reisen/reiseideen/wintersport-die-top-ten-der-schneesicheren-reiseziele-76861.html

Even without translating it you can get an impression where they have a lot of snow. They give more ideas, like Kuusamo und Ruka in Finnland. It has a lot of snow but it's not very steep there. So more a cross-country skying paradise.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what is meant by "snow days", the correct response to the question would have to be the Scandinavian countries in general. Within the Scandinavian region, Finland has the greatest number of snow days in Europe. Austria and Switzerland have half the number of snow days that Finland.

The ultimate area of recommendation to the question would have to be Finland!

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/figures/annual-number-of-days-with-snow-cover-over-european-land-areas-1961-1990-and-projected-change-for-2071-2100/map-5-16-climate-change-2008-annual-numbers-of-days.eps/image_large

http://web2.airmail.net/danb1/european.htm

http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/europe_map.htm